# C++ Strange Crash with msvcr90.dll!memcpy

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-cli, memcpy, msvcr90.dll

I am using 3rd party Decoder [ which is DivX] and in my application  I get

> "A first chance exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'
>   occurred"

When I look at stack trace, it seems that there is an error at memcpy in msvcr90.dll

> msvcr90.dll!memcpy(unsigned char * dst=0x00000000, unsigned char *
>   src=0x0ac766fe, unsigned long count=4294967248)  Line 188 Asm

I can not able to trace problem further in Visual C++ 2008...What may cause this, or any tools technics to get root cause of this strange error?

Comment: The cause is a NULL pointer being passed as the destination buffer to `memcpy()`.

Comment: I'd look at the stack again, to check MY code and see what my code has passed as arguments to the 3rd party lib. I see a `NULL` pointer in `memcpy`.

Comment: Also, the count argument is 4294967248 (=0xFFFFFFD0) which is a highly unlikely value.

Comment: Does the stack trace show you where `memcpy` is being called from? Have a look there to see why the first argument is null, and why the third seems to be -48.

Comment: Yes, stack trace show me where it called by i can not see its internals...It is a callback function without parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It look like a pointer to unallocated\desallocated memory and the count seam also weird.
You can try to debug\decompile it with OllyDBG or WinDBG and trace the problem.